# Enable anonymous bind in openldap

Tags: openldap

I have setup ldap server successfully and everything works find. However, i cannot access the server with 'anonymous' bind, which according to every google search it should be.

When I execute;

```
# ldapsearch -x -H ldap://localhost -b dc=example,dc=com
```

output says;

```
# result: 50 Insufficient access
```

Note: the only ACL exist is;

```
olcAccess: {0}to * by self write by anonymous auth by * none
```

Does this prove that the server is not compiler or configured to work with anonymous bind? And if so, what is the best way to enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone from ServerFault answered this question. 
https://serverfault.com/questions/748758/enable-anonymous-bind-in-openldap/748904#748904

Issue was the configured ACL. The line of **`by * none`** block most anonymous actions. Once get rid of that server allows to perform anonymous `ldapsearch` actions, proving, by default, openldap support anonymous bind.